# How to configure GeoServer to use .mbtiles osm map with the mb styles (map box styles)

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles

I am setting up GeoServer v2.20 to use .mbtiles osm(OpenStreetMap) vector tiles map file with the map box styles (style.json). Able to enable the MBTiles Store and MBStyle options by adding the corresponding extension for MBTiles & MBStyle in GeoServer.
The map is getting rendered via openLayers and the url for the map will look like as below:
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mydomain/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=layer_group_name&bbox=2117772.049113751%2C8242859.778951772%2C3517794.983414251%2C1.1101207517961873E7&width=376&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A3857&styles=&format=image%2Fpng

The map is getting rendered, however the following issues are occurring in the configuration and display as :

1. When saving the MB style (In GeoServer -> adding new Style), not able to save the details for 'background' layer type, am getting the error "Layer background:This layer is not meant to be transformed, but converted in a Style background fill". Hence I need to remove this section, in order to save the style.

```
"layers": [
    {
      "id": "background",
      "minzoom": 0,
      "paint": {
        "background-color": "rgba(239, 239, 228, 1)"
      },
      "type": "background"
    }
```

- May be because of this, in the Map view a lot of white color area is appearing for the map background with minimal zoom. But with maximum zoom level (17), am able to view most of the map information correctly.

2. There are lots of small red color square boxes are shown (as points) in the map. I guess its not able to get the correct styles/images for this points. In the MBStyle the 'sprite' attribute is specified as:

```
"name": "My custom map style",
  "pitch": 0,
  "sources": {
    "openmaptiles": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "#maptiler-osm"
    }
  },
  "sprite": "#",
  "version": 8,
  "zoom": 8.759936762170502
```

- Is there a way to point to the local directory for the sprite files (.json & .png) ?
  The same .mbtiles map file and the MB style are working fine with the MapTiler server, but not with the GeoServer as mentioned above.
  Would be great if any configuration steps are available / or any directions to make this work.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution finally?

Comment: @HosseinEbrahimi here is a howTo guide: https://github.com/geosolutions-it/openmaptiles